# Export a specific line in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a large XHTML file that contains a lot of code, see the below example:

```
<a:CreationDate>0</a:CreationDate>
<a:Creator/>
<a:ModificationDate>0</a:ModificationDate>
<a:Modifier/>
<a:name>stack</a:name>

<a:CreationDate>0</a:CreationDate>
<a:Creator/>
<a:ModificationDate>0</a:ModificationDate>
<a:Modifier/>
<a:name>user</a:name>
```

How can I export or select a specific line? In the example I want to have such result:

```
<a:name>stack</a:name>
<a:name>user</a:name>
```

and the rest of the code should be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the Notepad++ replace (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) in Regular Expression mode and search for this:

```
^((?!<a:name>.*</a:name>).)*$
```

And replace it with blank.

This is a negative look-around match that will select everything that is NOT contained between `<a:name> </a:name>` tags.

You can easily remove any remaining blank lines with the Notepad++ TextFX plugin 
(TextFX Edit->Delete Blank Lines)

Comment: can't vote up but you answer was good. Thanks